# CodeIgniter From Post Data Not Going through

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, upload

Im trying to make a file upload in CodeIgniter, how ever when I add enctype="multipart form-data" no post data will go through. At all not even the other fields. However when i dont add it, i can get the other post data, but of course no file upload. Whats going wrong here. Here is my view and controller:

View:

```
<h2>Add a New Album</h2>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photo/newAlbum">

                            <table style="margin-left:5px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>     Album Name:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>     Photo .zip File:</td>
                                    <td><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="Upload Photo File" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

</form>
```

controller only contains:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Result is:

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: controller is photo, method is newAlbum - I assume that var_dump is in method - what is in index and constructor ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add this form attribute:
`enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8"`
Instead of:
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`
You can see this [link](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1802).

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa, This solved a problem i've had for days now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the multipart data like image/zip or some other blob data will be included in $_FILES array, not $_POST array.
I recommend you to use the upload library.

view:upload_form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

view:upload_success.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

<ul>
<?php foreach($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
<li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<p><?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

controller:upload.php

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 }

 function index()
 { 
  $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
 }

 function do_upload()
 {
  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = '100';
  $config['max_width']  = '1024';
  $config['max_height']  = '768';

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
  {
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

   $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
  } 
  else
  {
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

   $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
  }
 } 
}
?>
```

And that's all

Answer (score 2):

You need fix your `do_upload`, like this..

```
$this->upload->do_upload('name-of-input-file-element-of-your-form')
```

For example, in your view code, you have:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

So, your `do_upload` line, should be like this:

```
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. The code you posted should work. I made a quick test script using your form, and both the $_FILES and $_POST data come through fine.

I found this previous question on SO: [PHP--parsing multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075513/php-parsing-multipart-form-data)

It sounds like the same problem you're having. Unfortunately no real answer was reached for that problem. I would think this might be a server configuration issue - can you try the same code on another server and see if it functions?

The only other bit of information I can find was in the answer to this question, [$_POST data returns empty when headers are > POST_MAX_SIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733256/post-data-returns-empty-when-headers-are-post-max-size)

If you are trying to upload too large a file, apparently that can cause PHP to throw away the $_POST data as well. But if you've tried submitting your form without uploading a file (but still using "multipart/form-data"), and still don't see any $_POST data coming through, that doesn't apply.

Comment: CodeIgniter unsets `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc... as a security measure and offers a managed way to access them via `$this->input->get("Foo");` It seems the managed access isn't populated for multipart forms

Comment: By default it does not destroy the global $_GET array and it doesn't seem to ever unset the $_POST global. It can be made to destroy the $_GET array with `$config['allow_get_array'] = FALSE` but the $_POST array appears to remain intact. The input helper functions only simplify retrieval from these arrays by returning false if the index does not exist. Otherwise so long as $_POST['foo'] is set `$this->input->post('foo')` and `$_POST['foo']` are equivalent. [CodeIgnitor User Guide Entry](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check for possible wrong redirection in CI layer. It could be caused by a wrong URL request (for example, a slash '/' missing at the end of the URL). Redirections delete any POST data (I was dealing with this).

So, be sure that you are using full URLs in form action.

Check for your .htaccess and `$config['uri_protocol']` consistency too.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.
I solved it this way. in application/config/config.php you set the base_url
please be aware of, that this url have to be exact the same as the one you're calling
your web app. For me, I called my domain with www.sdfsd.com, but in the config file
I wrote http://sdfsd.com and so the POST of the form didn't work. So I changed this
and now everything is working!!

cheers

Comment: Note that your base URL must match the `action` attribute of forms if you are using the full URL. For example if `base_url = http://www.mysite.com` and you use `<form method="post" action="http://mysite.com/my_script">` you will receive an empty $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I don't agree with the above answers.  I think the crucial thing is at what stage in your controller you attempt to get the post data.  Perhaps you could post the relevant part of your controller. I found that both the post data and the upload data only become available after you call

```
this->upload->do_upload()
```

Obviously, you use an if statement to check for success.  If successful,

```
$this->upload->data()
```

returns the standard array with info about the uploaded file and

```
$this->input->post('name_of_your_form_element')
```

is populated with what you entered in the relevant form element.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - Turns out POST data is empty when you exceed max upload size / max post size.
This answer fixed my problem and allowed me to see $_POST and $_FORM data: 
[$_POST data returns empty when headers are > POST_MAX_SIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733256/post-data-returns-empty-when-headers-are-post-max-size)