# Codeigniter no POST variables.

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

Have a problem with codeigniter and be trying to sort it for hours, Seems the post vars are not being posted, the form is working I tested it using the action as test.php (print_r()) in the file, and the vars are being posted OK, so its the controller that is not doing as it should.

Controller:

```
print_r($_POST); //Nothing
print_r($this->input->post()); //Nothing
print_r($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE)); //Nothing
exit;
```

Maybe its the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|img|images|frontcss|css|frontjs|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is your controller name ?? make sure your `.htaccess` doesn't contains any controller name

Comment: Are you coding the html in your view manually or using `form_open('name', '', $attrib );` If manually make sure you have a METHOD="POST" on the <form> tag

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register/login"> Thats the from name and I tried using the form_open and nothing, My controller name is register.php

Comment: This can happen if your post exceeds the max post size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733256/post-data-returns-empty-when-headers-are-post-max-size

Comment: Where is your code for your form display?

Answer (score 0):

Your mod_rewrite module doesn't exist. Install mod_rewrite.